# What is the best way to design calls of post and comments in a rest api?

Tags: rest, api, django

So, currently I have two models: `Post` and `Comment`. Where a post can have multiple comments.

I have an endpoint named `Posts` and an endpoint named `Comments` that is called to retrieve comments of a post.

currently I can call `/posts` to retrieve all posts, or call `/comments` to retrieve all comments.

But how do the url's need to look like? Which of the following is the best choice:

Get all comments of a post:

Method 1

```
GET /comments?post_id={post_id}
```

Method 2

```
GET /posts/{post_id}/comments
```

Create new comments:

Method 1

```
POST /comments
```

Method 2

```
POST /post/{post_id}/comments
```

I don't think this information matters but I'm using Django + DRF.

Comment: Both are perfectly fine, but I'd tend towards method 1 if there are scenarios in which you would like to operate on all comments, regardless of the post to which they belong. For example, an admin dashboard might `GET /comments?status=flagged`.

Comment: For maximum flexibility you can just implement both routes on the back-end, and have them call the same handler internally.  Then after a while, you can see which method to remove (if any), assuming it's not getting used.

Answer (score 1):

> how the urls need to looks like?

```
/comments?post_id={post_id}
/posts/{post_id}/comments
```

These are both *fine*.

The spelling that uses query parameters is a bit more comfortable to work with when you are using HTML Forms, because compliant browsers know how to convert form input controls into query parameters.

The spelling that uses path parameters is a bit more comfortable to work with when you have relative references, because we can use dot segments to work our way back up the stack of path segments.

There is no "best choice"; just trade offs.